# googlemaps marker not showing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to show map of Serbia and add marker to Belgrade, I get the map to show but not the marker.

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.112251, 20.735648),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

var markerOptions = {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(44.816037, 20.464954)
};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
marker.setMap(map)
```

I got all coordinates from google maps so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Assign your new map to a variable called map.

From: new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
To: var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

Comment: Thanks, I am completely new to googlemaps, but this was a dumb oversight. anyway, feel free to post this as the answer as it solved my problem.

Comment: It happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the new google map to a map variable :)

From:

```
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

To:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```